# backgroundTint in XML does not change color of BottomActionBar, even with min API >= 21

Tags: java, android, material-components, material-components-android, android-bottomappbar

I'm trying to set up a basic BottomActionBar with an attached FloatingActionButton. Currently, everything seems to work, aside from the background of the bar. If I use `android:background="some_background_color"`, the bar is filled in with the desired color.

The problem is that I want my FAB to be cradled, and this approach seems to be incompatible with `fabCradleMargin` and `fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius`, as the background bar is unaffected by modifying these values.

All tutorials indicate that `app:backgroundTint="some_background_color"` is the way to go, but my action bar remains unaffected by this. I've set my API to >= 21, so as far as I know, there are no issues there.

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
            app:fabAttached="true"
            app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
            app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="10dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal"
            app:fabSize="normal"/>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The backgroundTint has no effect on the bar; it remains completely white.

Sorry if this is an elementary question; I'm quite new to Android and have spent quite a while searching for a solution to no avail.

Comment: `app:backgroundTint="@color/..."` works. Use the version 1.1.0-beta01

Comment: I'm using 1.1.0-beta01, and `app:backgroundTint="@color/..."` does not work on my end.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code
it shows an error for `BottomAppBar` so I findout this code `app:fabAttached="true"` is Undefined...

remove it and it will work perfectly.
Goodluck.